# What's a good reference for the geometry of G/B and G/P?

Tags: reference-request

Is there a reference that develops the geometry of G/B and G/P where G is a Lie group, B a Borel, P a parabolic? More specifically, I would like a reference that does the Geometry section of Fulton's Young Tableaux more carefully.